# How to Calculate Target Destination

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, transform, renderer, qvector3d

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this one out. What I'm trying to achieve is a sort of tackling motion. The player lunges at the target from a distance.

[image]

The diagram shows the set up. The blue diamond is the player and the red thing is the target. The purple box is the renderer bounds of the targets SkinnedMeshRenderer. I'm using renderer bounds because some target's mesh are much larger than other. Currently, the player is shooting to the orange star...which is unrealistic. I want him to, no matter what way the target is facing, always target the closest point of the target relative to his position...in the diagram's case that would be the brown star. Here's the code I've been using...

```
 public IEnumerator Blitz()
{
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero; //ZERO OUT THE RIGIDBODY VELOCITY TO GET READY FOR THE BLITZ
    SkinnedMeshRenderer image = target.GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    Vector3 position = image.renderer.bounds.center + image.renderer.bounds.extents;
    position.y = target.transform.position.y;
    while(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, position) > 0.5f)
    {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, position, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        yield return null;
    }
    Results(); //IRRELEVANT TO THIS PROBLEM. THIS CALCULATES DAMAGE.
    Blitz.Stop(); //THE PARTICLE EFFECT ASSOCIATED WITH THE BLITZ.
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool(moveName, false); //TRANSITIONS OUT OF THE BLITZ ANIMATION
    GetComponent<Input>().NotAttacking(); //LET'S THE INPUT SCRIPT KNOW THE PLAYER CAN HAVE CONTROL BACK.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the derection to tarvel in and normalize it to length of 1
Vector3 Direction = (Target - transform.position).normalized
```

With Direction, you can do many things. For example, you can multiply the direction by your speed and add that to your position.

```
transform.position += Direction * MoveSpeed;
```

If you want to get to the closest point, you can use the handy Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds method.

```
Target = TargetObject.GetComponent<Collider>().ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position)
```

and plug the Target into the code used to get the direction.

Alternatively, you can use Vector3.Lerp without getting a direction since it's just interpolating.

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Target,transform.position,time.DeltaTime);
```

For stopping at the target point, you can use the arrival behavior.

```
//Declare the distance to start slowing down
float ClosingDistance = Speed * 2;
//Get the distance to the target
float Distance = (Target - transform.position).magnitude;
//Check if the player needs to slow down
if (Distance < ClosingDistance)
{
//If you're closer than the ClosingDistance, move slower
transform.position += Direction * (MoveSpeed * Distance / ClosingDistance);
}
else{
//If not, move at normal speed
transform.position += Directino * MoveSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Well I'm already using Vector3.Lerp... it's on the 9th line of my code. The Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds I didn't know about...and that sounds great! However, the issue still remains on stopping at just the right point to SIMULATE the collision of the player against the target. This is why I need to use the renderer.bounds as well. During an animation the collider doesn't change (at least not in my case), but the mesh does... So if the player is leaning forward, he's outside of his collider. To compensate for this I want to incorporate the renderer.bounds into the calculation.

Comment: By "stopping at just the right point" do you mean stopping when your player standing on the target position? If so, interpolation will do that for you. you can also use arrival behaviors which I'll add an explanation of in the answer.